# what is $E(a|b)$ and $F(a|b)$ in wolfram alpha indefinite integrals?

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

what does $E()$ and $F()$ in the indefinite integral solution given by wolfram alpha mean?

Also is there any relation between $E(-a|b)$ and $E(a|b)$?

[image]

Comment: It will help to know *which* indefinite integral solution.

Comment: See https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/EllipticIntegrals.html

Comment: @Jean-Claude Arbaut - Thank you for the reference

Comment: Note that Wolfram (and Mathematica) notation $E(\phi\mid m)$ is written elsewhere $E(\phi,k)$, where $k^2 = m$.